# Required Doctype properties

Tags: jquery, html

I have a page with the doctype:

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">`

and I am trying to run a jQuery animation on the page testing with IE8.  The animation does not work, and doesnt even attempt to animate even though the "animate complete" callback is fired.

If I change the doctype to:

`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`

The animation works perfect.  Is that added URL necessary or required?

Edit:  I should add, I do not have control over the HTML of the original page.  I just threw this doctype in to a test page to see if that was the issue.

Comment: The extra URL is part of [the standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/loosedtd.html).  Sounds like a quirks mode bug

Comment: It's typically best to just use `<!DOCTYPE html>` to put your page into standards mode; unless you have a specific reason for not doing so.

Comment: I would, but unfortunately i do not control the HTML, or else it would be regular ol' <!doctype html>

Comment: @jasonSperke  you should add that as an answer so i can give credit.  And thats all I needed to hear!  :-)

Comment: @Mike_G This might be a good time to encourage those who do control the markup to make this change; they could at least use the `x-ua-compatibile` header (or `meta` equivalent) to push pages into Standards Mode on a case-by-case basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL you're referring to points to the definition your document uses; [there are a few options](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.2).

It's likely you're experiencing issues between Quirks Mode (which makes IE8 behave like IE5.5), and Standards Mode. If you press F12 you should be able to identify which Document Mode you're in via the developer tools.

There are a few ways to put the browser back into standards mode:

- Send an `x-ua-compatible` header with a value of `IE=edge` in the HTTP response.
- Use the shorter `<!DOCTYPE html>` doctype
- Or use the `meta` tag to provide the `x-ua-compatible` instruction

Aside from these, if you cannot modify the markup, you will not be able to force the page into Standards. You can, of course, experience with Standards Mode by manually overriding the Document Mode in the developer tools; this won't affect any other users though.

Additional Reading:

- [Defining document compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Investigating Document Mode Issues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699340%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: +1 this answer is MUCH more complete than any I would have offered